# Cloud SQL Server on GCP is recreating if I am changing the root password in teraform

Tags: github, devops, google-cloud-sql, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm using Terraform to create a cloud SQL Server and specify its root password. When I use Terraform to change the root password for the same instance, it initially deletes the instance and then creates a new one with the new root password, which is not how it should work.

However, whether I use the console or the gcloud api to perform the same action. It enables me to modify the server's existing password.